# angular google maps v2.0.1 markers directive label will not display when hovered over

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-markers, angular-google-maps

In 1.2.x I used to set this in the options attribute. That still works for the marker directive but in 2.x that does not work for the markers (plural) directive. I tried using the labelContent (code snippet) and it didn't work either.

```
  <ui-gmap-markers models="SelectedHotels" idkey="'id'" coords="'self'" icon="'markerIcon'" click="'onClick'" dorebuildall="true" labelContent="'officeName'"
        labelVisible="true">
    </ui-gmap-markers>
```

You can see it in this plunker. The 2 right markers are the ones I'm targeting. The marker on the left is the single directive and the hover works on that one.  http://plnkr.co/edit/4eF1Wu4tURysTji0b5kO?p=preview

Comment: did you ever get this working? i find myself in a similar situation.

Comment: I ended up using google maps api directly @oj-raque%c3%b1o, I didn't use the ng library